# Change the button color by onclick event using Animations in Xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to change the color of the button when a user clicks on it,the click event is bindable i.e., implemented in ViewModel....when the user clicks on the button some kind of animation has to be done so that the user can know his selection

There is a possibility to this by binding the button color and in the method I can change the colours..But I want to achieve it using Animations(FadeTo,FadeIn) from ViewModel

Is It possible to do like this??

Thank You

Comment: The Animation extensions and parameters (i.e. the View/Property ones) are directly tied to the Xamarin.Forms Views which would break the ViewModel paradigm by including them inside those classes (and cause testing problems). Providing a ViewModel callback (on parameter change, command invocation, etc.) into your Page classes where the animations are defined would be preferred

Comment: Thank You @SushiHangover..I think this could be the only solution to achieve this